# which header do i need to send to browser when responding with flash file

Tags: flash, http

i build ed simple single threaded web server that i embedded to my application in Qt c++
this server are responding fine with simple html pages , but when i try to response with
flash file embedded inside the html all the html string just got printed to the browser
my question is what headers and http responses do i need to unable me to serve flash content to the   browser
Thanks

Comment: How are you "embedding" the flash file in the HTML? Normally it would be linked (a separate resource), not embedded. (Although you could probably use a data URI to embed it).

Comment: its out source (you tube player)

Comment: If html string gets printed to the browser, you might be sending it as `text/plain` instead of `text/html`

Comment: well now that im debugging the server i see im getting 2 requests 
1 with the html request and the second is the request for the flash file but the response is coming as download  file and not as rendered flash file .

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Type` header for SWF file should be set to `application/x-shockwave-flash`. Otherwise browser won't understand the file type and present it for downloading.